# I'm getting troubles while uploading to Youtube with google java client: "Invalid value for: listed is not a valid value"

Tags: youtube-api, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to upload videos using https://code.google.com/p/youtube-api-samples/source/browse/samples/java/youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/youtube_cmdline_uploadvideo_sample/UploadVideo.java example

I've successfully registered on the youtube console and have obtained the client_secrets.json at https://code.google.com/apis/console/?api=youtube#project:340964720118:access

I have installed the secrets so my app can access them; everything is compiled well, but when the program is executed, I'me getting that strange errors:

```
GoogleJsonResponseException code: 400 : Invalid value for: listed is not a valid value
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Invalid value for: listed is not a valid value",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid value for: listed is not a valid value"
}
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
```

I can't find out what is wrong; since the request itself is deeply encapsulated, I can't understand what is wrong with the request...

UPD.

Thanks to

```
 System.out.println(videoInsert.getHttpContent().toString());
```

call inserted before the

```
 Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
```

in the sample code, I got that the JSOn formed and sent to the google is

```
{snippet={description=Video uploaded via YouTube Data API V3 using the Java library on Sun Sep 29 20:29:30 MSK 2013, tags=[test], title=Test Upload via Java on Sun Sep 29 20:29:30 MSK 2013}, status={privacyStatus=listed}}
```

But actually there is still a question what is wong with this json and why it causes the error on the the server side.

UPD 2:

And no I no longer get the message above, but the upload is still impossible. I'm getting 401 Error while trying to upload the file in that lines of the example above:

```
        System.out.println(videoInsert.getJsonContent().toString());
        System.out.println(videoInsert.getHttpContent().getType());
        Video returnedVideo = videoInsert.execute();
        System.out.println(returnedVideo.getId());
```

I supposed that I haven't authorized the request to my personal data, but I actually DID it (the request was loaded to the default browser where I have accepted it and specified the account I would like to work with). However, there is no way to check that authoriation; my google account data holds only Apps and Activity log for the google+ apps; I haven't fount my app in the list. So where I can check where I'm not logged in?

```
IOException: 401 Unauthorized
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 401 Unauthorized
at      com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:423)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at ScreenRecordingExample.UploadToYoutube(ScreenRecordingExample.java:356)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the UPD-2 problem was resolved unfortunately in the way i don't know exactly how:

i have noticed, that in my code example there was a line

```
return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, localReceiver).authorize("user");
```

I have replaced 'user' with my google user name (but actually I'm not sure that it was a thing that was really needed). After that replacement the authorization attempt started again (default browser loaded the accept/decline page and there I should select one of two accounts). Since I have two accounts, the original youtube one and the common google one, and during the last attempt I have selected the google's one and got 401 error, I have selected the youtube's one this time.

so, after that the problem was resolved. I still don't know do it due to the correct username instead of 'user' or due to the correct account selection. If someoune kows the truth, please comment!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found out that the problem appeared due to the incorrect privacyStatus value:

I had

```
status.setPrivacyStatus("listed");
```

in my code, while it seems that only public, unlisted and private are possible values